# Class 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource' not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Where do I suppose to indicate class dependency when I got error messages:

- *Class 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource' not found*
- *Class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' not found*

**jdbc-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
        p:user="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        p:acquireIncrement="5"
        p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
        p:maxPoolSize="100"
        p:maxStatements="50"
        p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I suggest to use the same version of namespaces. In your case take 2.5 or 3.0.
Or even [current version](http://www.springframework.org/schema/) 
But do not use different versions in same project.

About your first problem:

> Class 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource' not found

Have you included in your classpath 'c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar'?

In second case you should include to classpath 'spring-jdbc-x.x.jar' depending the version of Spring you decide to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
Class 'com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource' not found
```

I resolve this error by copying the `c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar` file to the `WEB-INF/lib folder.c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar` file was founded by google searching

Comment: latest dependency at : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.5